# Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I’m new to android, I’m trying to do an application using Broadcast Receiver which send the message to notification bar when wallpaper is changed on device. It’s successfully installed on device but not working as expected. Here is the code

WallPagerNotificationReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WallPaperNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                                this.sendNotification(context, "You have changed Wallpaper");
    }
    private void sendNotification(Context ctx, String message)
    {
                //Get the notification manager
                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager nm =
                                (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(ns);

                //Create Notification Object
                                int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                                CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
                                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                Notification notification =
                                                new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

                                //Set ContentView using setLatestEvenInfo
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);
                    notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, "Intimation", message, pi);

                    //Send notification
                                nm.notify(1, notification);
                                Toast.makeText(ctx,"Hello Nawin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Manifest.xlm

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.ac.srmuniv"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <receiver android:name=".WallPaperNotificationReceiver">
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Is this right way to use Broadcast receiver? if so Help me where I did a mistake?

Thanks in Advance.

P.S: I’m not using either Activity or Service. According to the process life cycle we can have a foreground process by hosting a broadcast receiver http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the expected behaviour and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: My expected result is to get the Notification message when i change the wallpaper. My problem is Now i'm not getting any notification even i change the wallpaper

Comment: I put a fix for the receiver below. I haven't tested your Notification code, however. Best to use a Toast in your onReceive method so that you know you have received the broadcast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Android version 3.1 BroadcastReceivers that are registered only in the manifest and in an app which has no Activity, will not work. Each app must have an activity which must be run at least once to enable the receiver to work. This is to prevent malware. You just need a dummy activity which does nothing then quits to run once and make your receiver work.

Answer (score 2):

Change receiver to:

```
<receiver android:name=".WallPaperNotificationReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the actual broadcast:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED

Comment: See NickT's post. That I wasn't aware of, although I never had the requirement to do such a thing. The above receiver is correct, however.

Answer (score 1):

Put some logging statements in your code to determine if the Broadcast Receiver is being called at all.

If it is not, investigate the cause for this (incorrect manifest etc)

If the Broadcast Receiver is being called then your code that builds the notification is wrong.

Comment: I checked with logging statement, Broadcast receiver is not being triggered :(

Comment: If it is not triggered it is a problem with your manifest. Try specifying a full package name instead of just ".WallPaperNotificatiobReceiver". Also make sure your receiver is named exactly the same as what you are declaring in your manifest.